# First check for errors before submitting

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a form which I want it to be verified and validated by a try-catch block plus two other functions.
Here is what I have:
**HTML:**

```
<h5>Please enter your name below</h5>

<form name="textForm">
    <label for="name">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="name">
</form>

<h5>Please enter your e-mail below</h5>

<form name="mailForm">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
</form>
    <form action="">
<label for="height">Your height:</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="in centimetres" name="personHeight" id="height" />
<br></br>
<input formaction="mailto:test@gmail.com" onclick="heightCheck();validateTextForm();validateMailForm();" type="submit" value="Submit all" id="submit" method="post" formtarget="_blank" />
<br></br>
<p id="mess"></p>
    </form>
```

**JS**:

```
function validateTextForm() {
    var x = document.forms["textForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}

function validateMailForm() {
    var z = document.forms["mailForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = z.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = z.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= z.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}

function heightCheck() {
    try {
        var x = document.getElementById("height").value; 
        if (x == "")   
        throw "enter your height"; 
        if (isNaN(x)) throw "not a number";
        if (x > 250)    
        throw "height is too high";
        if (x < 80)     
        throw "height is too low"; 
    } catch (err) {
        var y = document.getElementById("mess");
        y.innerHTML = "Error: " + err + "."; 
    }
}
```

The thing that i want it to happen is the following: Firstly, it does the form validation but afterwards if its correct, submits as well.
I tried to make it first verify the forms before actually submits but without any success.
While browsing i find out it could be done by either `stopPropaganation`, `preventDefault` or `return false` methods but still have no idea how to make it happen.
I will rep the guys who help me. Thanks in advance!
Fiddle: However in fiddle it doesn't run properly as it should: http://jsfiddle.net/5T9sJ/

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code according to my editions:

```
...
<input formaction="mailto:test@gmail.com" type="submit" value="Submit all" id="submit" method="post" formtarget="_blank" />
...
```

Then make `processValidate` method to wrap all other validations into it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input#submit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        validateTextForm();
        validateMailForm();
        heightCheck();
    });

    function validateTextForm() {
        var x = document.forms["textForm"]["fname"].value;
        if (x === null || x === "") {
            alert("First name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }

    function validateMailForm() {
        var z = document.forms["mailForm"]["email"].value;
        var atpos = z.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = z.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= z.length) {
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
            return false;
        }
    }

    function heightCheck() {
        try {
            var x = document.getElementById("height").value;
            if (x === "") throw "enter your height";
            if (isNaN(x)) throw "not a number";
            if (x > 250) throw "height is too high";
            if (x < 80) throw "height is too low";
        } catch (err) {
            var y = document.getElementById("mess");
            y.innerHTML = "Error: " + err + ".";
        }
    }

});
```

**Explanation:**

You have several methods bound on **submit** input  type, so clicking on it will always call form submission.

I added jQuery `click` handler for this action to prevent the default action of submit button.

I think `e.preventDefault()` suits here the best.

**WORKING DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rbegf/

Comment: I tried but somehow the validate and height functions didn't occur. Just the formaction attr did.

Comment: Here is what it shows up: `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined asd.js:9
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'preventDefault' of undefined` P.S. In jsfiddle it says that processValidate is not definited.

Comment: See my edit, i added jsfiddle demo. Use jQuery to make things easier

Comment: I am quite curious how it seems to be 'working' in fiddle but actually as separated .html and .js files it seems to not be working at all (it just does trigger the submit button without any preventDefault and errors). Fair enough..

Comment: Ok... Before complaining here, try to look the CONSOLE logs of the browser and search in google for errors and fix them. You probably forgot to inclune jquery-1.9.1.js file before your script. If it works in fiddle, than it MUST work as separate files. Try to learn jquery and js basics with HTML.